# Generalizing rising and falling factorial to complex arguments preserving zeroes

Tags: factorial, analytic-continuation

Falling factorials count injective functions. There are no injective functions $ A \to B $ if $|A| \gt |B|$ . Is there a way to extend the definition of the falling factorial, ideally to $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, so that the zeroes are preserved? The most obvious way of informally generalizing the falling factorial involves taking ratios of the gamma function, but I'm not convinced that that works out.

---

When the right argument of the rising factorial is a natural number, it is defined in the following way:

$$ (x)^{\overline{k}} \stackrel{df}{=} \prod_{i = 0}^{k-1} (x + i) $$

$$ (x)^{\overline{k}} = (x)(x+1)\cdots(x+k-2)(x+k-1) $$

And the falling factorial is defined in the following way

$$ (x)^{\underline{k}} \stackrel{df}{=} \prod_{i = 0}^{k-1} (x - i) $$

$$ (x)^{\underline{k}} = (x)(x-1)\cdots (x-k+2)(x-k+1) $$

The falling factorial can be defined in terms of the rising factorial in two ways.

$$ (x)^{\underline{k}} = (-1)^k (-x)^{\overline{k}} $$

or

$$ (x)^{\underline{k}} = (x-k+1) ^ {\overline{k}} $$

The rising factorial satisfies the following identity:

$$ (x)^{\overline{k}} = \frac{(x+k-1)!}{(x-1)!} $$

Which suggests the generalization

$$ (x)^{\overline{k}} = \frac{\Gamma(x+k)}{\Gamma(x)} $$

and

$$ (x)^{\underline{k}} = \frac{\Gamma(x + 1)}{\Gamma(x-k + 1)} $$

This makes me nervous since $0 \notin \text{Im}(\Gamma)$ and $\Gamma$ has a pole when $ x \le -1 $ .

---

Does a nice way of extending the rising/falling factorial to complex arguments exist?

Comment: I do not know a better way than through the gamma ratio you show. Of course, the poles in the numerator will cancel with the denominator if both are negative integers

Comment: by the way, it is actually $$
x^{\,\underline {\,k\,} }  = \left( {x - k + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  = {{\Gamma (x + 1)} \over {\Gamma (x - k + 1)}}
$$